What's wrong with this BeforeSave VB?
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If Cells(11, 5) = "" Then
MsgBox "Cell K5 Required.", vbInformation, "Action Required"
Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
End Sub
New to VB. Watched a few videos that show this was the correct way to do what I want. K5 cell needs to be filled out before the file can be saved. Now, it doesn't matter if there is data in cell K5 or not - It wont let you save and keeps giving me the custom message.
Tried playing around with "<>" instead of "=" and added a space between the ""'s.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
